# c# Regex problem

Tags: c#, regex

i want search a value in on row like this

```
<p align="center"><input type="hidden" name="e79e7ec" value="15302f565b">
```

i need name="" value and value="" value :P create this code , but this code dosent work

```
Regex rloginRand = new Regex(@"<p align=center><input type=hidden name=\w*");
            Match mloginRand = rloginRand.Match(source);
            string loginrand = "";
            if (mloginRand.Success)
            {
                 loginrand = mloginRand.ToString().Replace("<p align=center><input type=hidden name=", "");
            }
            string loginrnd = "";
            Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+"value=\w*");
            Match mloginRnd = rloginRnd.Match(source);

            if (mloginRand.Success)
            {
                loginrnd = mloginRnd.ToString().Replace("name="+loginrand+" value=", "");
            }
```

error is

Form1.cs(71,69): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

at this line

Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+"***value=\w****");

Comment: regex html strikes again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an `@` before each part of the string:

```
Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+@"value=\w*");
```

Comment: i do that but nothing returend

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the problem is that you don't need to search for "name=" in the second Regex, since that has already been taken care of in the first one.

Answer (score 4):

Regex is not always the best tool for HTML; I'd use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) (since it isn't xhtml), and xpath - it should be pretty trivial then:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("input");
    // read (if you want)
    string name = node.GetAttributeValue("name", ""),
        value = node.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
    // wipe
    node.SetAttributeValue("name", loginrand);
    node.SetAttributeValue("value", "");
    // get html
    html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

use
`Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+@"*value=\w**");`
Note: Second @ sign

or
`Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+"*value=\\w**");`
Note: Double \ before w

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the @ covers the entire string concatination, only the bit that it's on.

Try.

```
Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+ @"*value=\w**");
```

or

```
Regex rloginRnd = new Regex(@"name="+ loginrand+ "*value=\\w**");
```

or use string.format